# Fragment cannot be converted to SupportMapFragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I made this app like 1 year ago and when I open it up it pops up with a bunch of totally random errors...probably due to updates but then

```
error: incompatible types: Fragment cannot be converted to SupportMapFragment
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

Maps Activity Code:

```
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    public GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> listAddresses =geocoder.getFromLocation(MainActivity.Globals.Latitude, MainActivity.Globals.Longitude,1);

            if (listAddresses != null && listAddresses.size() > 0) {
                String address = "";

                if (listAddresses.get(0).getThoroughfare() != null) {
                    address += listAddresses.get(0).getThoroughfare() + " ";//Address
                }
                if (listAddresses.get(0).getLocality() != null) {
                    address += listAddresses.get(0).getLocality() + " "; //City
                }
                if (listAddresses.get(0).getAdminArea() != null) {
                    address += listAddresses.get(0).getAdminArea() + " ";//State
                }
                if (listAddresses.get(0).getCountryName() != null) {
                    address += listAddresses.get(0).getCountryName() + " ";//Country
                }
                if (listAddresses.get(0).getAdminArea() != null) {
                    address += listAddresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                }

                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Customization
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        UiSettings uiSettings = mMap.getUiSettings();
        uiSettings.setCompassEnabled(true);
        uiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        LatLng person = new LatLng(MainActivity.Globals.Latitude, MainActivity.Globals.Longitude);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(person).title("Person").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(person,12));
    }
}
```

If it helps android studio made me change some gradle stuff

GradleProperties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Adding Jetifiers to this gives me a whole bunch of errors so I didn't do that

Build.Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'Name'
            keyPassword 'Password'
            storeFile file('/Location')
            storePassword 'Password'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.appMaps"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 7
        versionName '7.0'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible,GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible,GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: don't use fragmentActivty use Appcompact . and if you want to use this in fragment you can use MapView  instead of fragment .

Answer (score 0):

The final solution which worked was using AppCompatActivity instead of FragmentActivity
and then also had to enable Jetifier(Can anyone explain what Jetifier is and why it is used)
also had to make some changes in the main code to use snacker

Literally had to change everything to androidX